# How to get codemirror 'change' event to fire in Grapesjs plugin

Tags: javascript, events, onchange, codemirror, grapesjs

I'm building a Grapesjs plugin and have added a 'jscript' trait to a button component, which appears as a codemirror textarea. The idea is for users to be able to edit some javascript code associated with a button. I can't seem to intercept the codemirror area's `change` event, at least, not the proper codemirror specific version.

Happily, when I edit the codemirror area and change focus, a regular 'change' event triggers the Grapejs `onEvent` handler within my plugin's `editor.TraitManager.addType('jcodemirror-editor', {}` - good. I can then store the contents of the codemirror area into the trait.

```js
onEvent({ elInput, component, event }) {
    let code_to_run = elInput.querySelector(".CodeMirror").CodeMirror.getValue()
    component.getTrait('jscript').set('value', code_to_run);
},
```

However if we paste or backspace or delete etc. in the codemirror area then the regular 'change' event is never issued!

So I'm trying to intercept the deeper codemirror specific 'change' event which is usually intercepted via `cm.on("change", function (cm, changeObj) {}` and which is triggered more reliably (unfortunately also on each keystroke). How do I wire this codemirror specific event to trigger the usual `onEvent({ elInput, component, event }) {}` code?

I have a workaround in place in my https://jsfiddle.net/tcab/1rh7mn5b/ but would like to know the proper way to do this.

My Plugin:

```js
function customScriptPlugin(editor) {

    const codemirrorEnabled = true  // otherwise trait editor is just a plain textarea

    const script = function (props) {
        this.onclick = function () {
            eval(props.jscript)
        }
    };

    editor.DomComponents.addType("customScript", {
        isComponent: el => el.tagName == 'BUTTON' && el.hasAttribute && el.hasAttribute("data-scriptable"),
        model: {
            defaults: {
                traits: [
                    {
                        // type: 'text',
                        type: 'jcodemirror-editor',  // defined below
                        name: 'jscript',
                        changeProp: true,
                    }
                ],
                script,
                jscript: `let res = 1 + 3; console.log('result is', res);`,
                'script-props': ['jscript'],
            },
        },
    });

    editor.TraitManager.addType('jcodemirror-editor', {
        createInput({ trait }) {
            const el = document.createElement('div');
            el.innerHTML = `
                <form>
                    <textarea id="myjscript" name="myjscript" rows="14">
                    </textarea>
                </form>
            </div>
            `

            if (codemirrorEnabled) {
                const textareaEl = el.querySelector('textarea');
                var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textareaEl, {
                    mode: "javascript",
                    lineWrapping: true,
                });

                // This is the 'more accurate' codemirror 'change' event
                // which is triggered key by key. We need it cos if we paste
                // or backspace or delete etc. in codemirror then the
                // regular 'change' event is never issued! But how do we get
                // this event to trigger the proper, usual 'onEvent' below?
                // Currently cheating and doing the onEvent work here with
                // this special handler.
                myCodeMirror.on("change", function (cm, changeObj) { // HACK
                    const component = editor.getSelected()
                    const code_to_run = myCodeMirror.getValue()
                    component.getTrait('jscript').set('value', code_to_run);
                    console.log('onEvent hack - (myCodeMirror change event) updating jscript trait to be:', code_to_run)

                })
            }

            return el;
        },

        // UI textarea & codemirror 'change' events trigger this function,
        // so that we can update the component 'jscript' trait property.
        onEvent({ elInput, component, event }) {
            let code_to_run

            if (codemirrorEnabled)
                code_to_run = elInput.querySelector(".CodeMirror").CodeMirror.getValue()
            else
                code_to_run = elInput.querySelector('textarea').value

            console.log('onEvent - updating jscript trait to be:', code_to_run)
            component.getTrait('jscript').set('value', code_to_run);
        }, // onEvent

        // Updates the trait area UI based on what is in the component.
        onUpdate({ elInput, component }) {
            console.log('onUpdate - component trait jscript -> UI', component.get('jscript'))

            if (codemirrorEnabled) {
                const cm = elInput.querySelector(".CodeMirror").CodeMirror
                cm.setValue(component.get('jscript'))

                // codemirror content doesn't appear till you click on it - fix with this trick
                setTimeout(function () {
                    cm.refresh();
                }, 1);
            }
            else {
                const textareaEl = elInput.querySelector('textarea');
                textareaEl.value = component.get('jscript')

                // actually is this even needed as things still update automatically without it?
                // textareaEl.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change'));
            }

        }, // onUpdate

    }) // addType

    editor.BlockManager.add(
        'btnRegular',
        {
            category: 'Basic',
            label: 'Regular Button',
            attributes: { class: "fa fa-square-o" },
            content: '<button type="button">Click Me</button>',
        });

    editor.BlockManager.add(
        'btnScriptable',
        {
            category: 'Scriptable',
            label: 'Scriptable Button',
            attributes: { class: "fa fa-rocket" },
            content: '<button type="button" data-scriptable="true">Run Script</button>',
        });
}



const editor = grapesjs.init({
    container: '#gjs',
    fromElement: 1,
    height: '100%',
    storageManager: { type: 0 },
    plugins: ['gjs-blocks-basic', 'customScriptPlugin']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official Grapesjs documentation on traits [integrating external ui components](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Traits.html#integrate-external-ui-components) you can trigger the `onEvent` event manually by calling `this.onChange(ev)`.

So within `createInput` I continued to intercept the more reliable `myCodeMirror.on("change", ...` event and within that handler triggered the `onEvent` manually viz:

```js
editor.TraitManager.addType('jcodemirror-editor', {
    createInput({ trait }) {
        const self = this  // SOLUTION part 1
        
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = `
            <form>
                <textarea id="myjscript" name="myjscript" rows="14">
                </textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        `

        if (codemirrorEnabled) {
            const textareaEl = el.querySelector('textarea');
            var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textareaEl, {
                mode: "javascript",
                lineWrapping: true,
            });

            myCodeMirror.on("change", function (cm, changeObj) {
                self.onChange(changeObj) // SOLUTION part 2
            })
        }

        return el;
    },
```